# Got auto-granting bounty on a question that didn't get a true answer

Tags: support, reputation, bounties

I've put a large bounty on a question I really wanted an answer to, and yet all answers didn't have a working solution:

[How to avoid blocking of scrolling itself when using setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44484950/878126)

Sadly, some of them got upvoted, and the system decided to grant a bounty to one of them.

I didn't have the chance of extending the bounty period, or offer a larger bounty.

I tried to downvote all answers (because none had a working solution), but it still granted the bounty to one of them.

I also tried to flag the question to the moderator, to consider to extend my bounty, but it didn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: Even if the bounty hadn't been awarded to an answer you'd still have lost it so does it really matter? Just move on there's nothing else you can do.

Comment: @RobertLongson I would prefer to extend it, even at the cost of making the bounty larger. I don't even think they tested the solutions well, or at all, before posting. Is there any way to contact the creators of this website, to allow this behavior?

Comment: We'd need to charge rep for extending so it would work functionally like raising a new bounty. So just raise a new bounty and get the same effect. There's already a feature request to [extend bounties](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295298/add-an-option-to-extend-bounties).

Comment: @RobertLongson Will raising a new bounty cancel the granting of the previous one?

Comment: no it won't. There's no way to do that.

Comment: @RobertLongson That's too bad. Maybe I should have set the max bounty in the first time. Then again, this issue could happen in this case too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can't do that.

## Flagged for mod.

They will take action only if the question should be closed or should be deleted one(rare exceptions are there).

## Extent

No. after 7 days + 1 day grace period, the validity will be over.

## Not to award to an answer

If you didn't awarded, the Community user will award if there is an answer match the criteria.

- Full  bounty if the answer is posted in the bounty period + have 2 upvote + accepted.
- Half bounty If the answer is posted in the bounty period + have 2 upvotes.

> note : If there is an accepted answer with 3 votes and another one with 2 votes, the old one will be chosen(posted within bounty period).

If no answers are eligible, the bounty will be removed.

## Want to offer a larger bounty, you can do that now without any problem if you have enough rep.

Comment: What do you mean "you can't do that" ? Can't do what? Also, nothing I can do except adding a new bounty? Can the same issue occur again with the new bounty? What would have happened if it was the max bounty (500 points) ? Will I still be able to put a new bounty? Or will the system block me from doing anything related to bounties?

Comment: If you put a new bounty of 500 and if new answers are there with 2 upvotes, they will automatically get 250.

Comment: The system won't block you

Comment: But there are answers there that got 2 upvotes, which is why they got the bounty. This means they will get it again?!

Comment: no. as I mentioned, answers posted only in bounty period will be eligible for auto award of bounty. I just missed a 300 yesterday for posting one day before.

Comment: What do you mean by "answers posted only in bounty period "? Only new answers that are posted after putting a new bounty will be able to get the new award? Also, what do you mean "you can't do that" ? Can't do what?

Comment: _you can't do that_. you can't prevent bounty from awarded to an answer.

Comment: Bounty period means answers posted after you put the bounty and before the expire of bounty. Grace period won't counted.

Comment: So existing answers can't get a bounty automatically? Only new ones?

Comment: yes. Otherwise, you have to award it.

Comment: Well at least that... Thank you. Sadly I won't be able to handle bounties in the coming weeks. Will try it again later.